# In DolphindDB, is it feasible to use the SET...IF statement with UPDATE in SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

Does DolphinDB support the following script?

```
update tmp set exchangecd='XSHG' if exchangecd='SH' set exchangecd='XSHE' if exchangecd='sz'
```

Comment: Try it and see?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DolphinDB does not support the `IF` statement, but you can use the `CASE` statement with `WHEN...THEN...`, as shown in the following script:

```
UPDATE tmp SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 = 'SH' THEN 'hello1' WHEN col1 = 'SZ' THEN 'hello2'    ELSE col1END;
```